# Improved layered navigation suggestions

Tags: layered-navigation

I am looking to buy a module (or if there is free one) to improve layered navigation.

I am looking for something with fast filtering, SEO, multiple selections (I sell wheels so might need to select 17" and 18". Default navigation wont allow this)

Does anyone have experience of a improved navigation system to suggest? I am happy to buy one but want to make sure I am getting the right thing for the money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a few options to work with. First of all why doens't Magento default layered navigation allow you to use wheel size as a filtering option. If you configure your attribute as a select input and specify the values you are able to use it as a filtering option.

If you mean that you want to make it possible to select multiple wheelsizes you do need to extend the default Magento functionality. A great free extension is: [multiple select in layered navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html)

If you're looking for a complete Layered Navigation system that will seriously improve your webshops' filtering functionality I suggest you have a look at the Mandev extension (pricy but worth it in my opinion): [Mandev Layered Navigation](http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus)

**I'm not invested in any of these extensions just a happy user

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly the answer I was after. The standard filters are ok but as you say I need customers to select multiples and not just the one option.

I did try that free extension already but the filtering took forever (in fact I think it just locked up and never loaded the available products)

I will take a look at the paid system you linked to. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome Steve and good luck with the customization. Maybe you could accept the provided answer so it might help others as well. Thanks!